# D3.js Force Layout Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently trying to construct a very basic graph using d3.js' force layout. I am running into the error: "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" when I am trying to run my code, and was hoping someone could tell me what was wrong.

The error occurs at line #6388 in d3.js version 3.5.6, the line is:

```
neighbors[o.source.index].push(o.target);
```

The problem that it is running into is that the object o.source does not contain a property named index, even though that property should have been set previously in the force.start() function as seen in the following code:

```
force.start = function() {
  var i, n = nodes.length, m = links.length, w = size[0], h = size[1], neighbors, o;
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    (o = nodes[i]).index = i;
    o.weight = 0;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    o = links[i];
    if (typeof o.source == "number") o.source = nodes[o.source];
    if (typeof o.target == "number") o.target = nodes[o.target];
    ++o.source.weight;
    ++o.target.weight;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    o = nodes[i];
    if (isNaN(o.x)) o.x = position("x", w);
    if (isNaN(o.y)) o.y = position("y", h);
    if (isNaN(o.px)) o.px = o.x;
    if (isNaN(o.py)) o.py = o.y;
  }
  distances = [];
  if (typeof linkDistance === "function") for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) distances[i] = +linkDistance.call(this, links[i], i); else for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) distances[i] = linkDistance;
  strengths = [];
  if (typeof linkStrength === "function") for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) strengths[i] = +linkStrength.call(this, links[i], i); else for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) strengths[i] = linkStrength;
  charges = [];
  if (typeof charge === "function") for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) charges[i] = +charge.call(this, nodes[i], i); else for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) charges[i] = charge;
  function position(dimension, size) {
    if (!neighbors) {
      neighbors = new Array(n);
      for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        neighbors[j] = [];
      }
      for (j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
        var o = links[j];
        neighbors[o.source.index].push(o.target);
        neighbors[o.target.index].push(o.source);
      }
    }
    var candidates = neighbors[i], j = -1, l = candidates.length, x;
    while (++j < l) if (!isNaN(x = candidates[j][dimension])) return x;
    return Math.random() * size;
  }
  return force.resume();
};
```

From what I have been able to find on this topic already, it seems to be that the issue could be with how my nodes and links arrays are formatted. I can't seem to find the problem with them so maybe you can. My nodes array contains objects that look like this:

```
{
games: [...], 
id: 'some id'
}
```

and my link objects look like this:

```
{
source: nodeObject, 
target: nodeObject, 
weight: number
}
```

My code for setting up the force layout is below:

```
var force = d3.layout.force().charge(-1000)
  .size([500, 500])
  .nodes(nodes)
  .links(edges)
  .linkStrength(function(d) {
    return weightScale(d.weight);
  })
  .on('tick', forceTick);

d3.select('svg').selectAll('line.link')
  .data(edges, function(d) {
    return d.source.id + '-' + d.target.id;
  })
  .enter()
  .append('line')
  .attr('class', 'link')
  .style('stroke', 'black')
  .style('opacity', 0.5)
  .style('stroke-width', function(d) {
    return d.weight;
  });

var nodeEnter = d3.select('svg').selectAll('g.node')
  .data(nodes, function(d) {
    return d.id;
  })
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'node');
```

Can anyone help me figure out why I am getting the error I mentioned above? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Are you putting the node object references onto the link source and target properties your self or is it initially the index into the nodes array? If the former, try starting the data with node index instead and see if that fixes it.

Comment: This does fix the issue, but can you tell me what the correct way of doing this would be without having to rely on array position? It requires me to make another pass through my data which I would very much like to avoid. Thank you!

Comment: If you post a minimum _working_ example of your original code then I can take a look... it depends how your data is bound.